# My RAM usage never goes over 75% when system is lagging and under heavy load

Tags: linux, memory, ram, zram

```
Linux matrix 5.15.2-xanmod1-1 #1 SMP Wed, 17 Nov 2021 02:36:25 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                           
├─sda1 btrfs        swap  477dd81e-6a88-4987-b830-47bea1ec1f5d       0    87% /swap
└─sda2 btrfs        root  2067df62-8ff6-4b52-9814-e4d5d8cf1577   55.3G    48% /
zram0                                                                         [SWAP]
```

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.8Gi       1.2Gi       111Mi        56Mi       557Mi       446Mi
Swap:          5.5Gi       1.6Gi       3.9Gi
```

`vm.swappiness = 10`

So my issue is that when ever my system is under load, ie if I have too many tabs open in firefox, or running vscode and firefox at the same time, my system gets really laggy.

However, when I check the RAM usage its stuck at 75% and never goes over that. So there is 25% of unused RAM.

How do I get it to use more ram before swapping.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're assuming the slowness is due to the full `RAM`, which is not necessarily the root cause. Theoretically there should be other reasons and bottlenecks that would lead to slowness occurrences, such as extensive `I/O`, too many `processes` expecting CPU etc, and you should first rule out other reasons before you decide the culprit is the memory. You could use `vmstat` command, for instance:

```
$ vmstat -w 1 
procs -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- --------cpu--------
 r  b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us  sy  id  wa  st
 0  0            0    120951240         9412      8313416    0    0     0     2    0    0   0   0 100   0   0
 0  0            0    120951248         9412      8313416    0    0     0     0  143  210   0   0 100   0   0
 0  0            0    120950980         9412      8313416    0    0     0    20  116  238   0   0 100   0   0
 0  0            0    120950980         9412      8313416    0    0     0     0  180  315   0   0 100   0   0
 0  0            0    120951232         9412      8313416    0    0     0     0  145  285   0   0 100   0   0
```

If you see relatively high numbers under the `swap` section - `si` (`swap in`) or `so` (`swap out`) - that could indicate that the system is working out on swapping memory pages in and out the `RAM` to or from the `swap`. If the values there are low, there's probably another reason for the slowness (which you could probably see under `procs`, `io` or `cpu`).

Assuming you do see high `swap in/out` values in `vmstat`, that indicates that the bottleneck is indeed the `RAM` getting filled up.

Here's the description of `swappiness` from the [Linux kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt#L809):

> swappiness
>
> This control is used to define how aggressive the kernel will swap
> memory pages.  Higher values will increase aggressiveness, lower
> values decrease the amount of swap.  A value of 0 instructs the kernel
> not to initiate swap until the amount of free and file-backed pages is
> less than the high water mark in a zone.
>
> The default value is 60.

First, notice that your `swappiness` value (`10`) is significantly lower than the default (`60`).

Let's say your `firefox` has a lot of tabs; Most of them are idle and aren't used much. If the `swappiness` is low, the machine will try to keep their data in RAM as much as possible and to avoid swapping out until it **really** has to free some memory for new pages; This means that the machine will start swapping only in times of need, and then it might be a bit too late, and at that moment you'll see some lagging waiting for the old memory pages to get swap out.

If the `swappiness` is higher, the system will page out old and idle memory pages more frequently and ahead of time, leaving more of your memory free for new pages. When you access those tabs again it will page in their memory from disk to RAM so it might be slower, but since you don't use those tabs very frequently it's better to keep them in swap and keep more free memory pages available for new processes.

I would suggest to increase your `swappiness`, so old and unused memory pages are swapped out more frequently and not only when the memory reaches its limit.

Comment: Your advice helped me figure out the source of the problem. Increasing the swappiness did make it less laggy, but the real issue was with `zram`. 

It had a lower swap priority than the slower disk partition, but I guess it was still preallocating the ram space. `/dev/zram0` wasn't getting used at all. So I increased the priority with
```
swapon --priority 100 /dev/zram0 --fixpgsz && swapon --priority 90 /swap/swapfile --fixpgsz
```
So now all my ram is being used. Much Thx